# How to set body inside a Promise?

Tags: node.js, promise, koa, document-body, koa-router

In code bellow, I would like that somehow changed commented part should be able to set document's body instead of "this.body = 'test';" (it still should be Promise solution).

```
'use strict'

var app = require('koa')(),
    router = require('koa-router')();

router.get('/', function *(next) {
    this.body = 'test';
    // var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    //   resolve("test");
    // });
    // promise.then(function(res){
    //   this.body = res;
    // })
});

app
  .use(router.routes())

app.listen(8000);
```

The problem is that "this" inside a Promise is not referred to "the right one".

Comment: document's body is client side you should use a template engine and send the variable to be changed to the layout where the `<body>` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds quite like a duplicate of [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572) (with the solution being using an arrow function for the callback), but actually you don't need those callbacks at all with koa (and co). You can just yield the promise!

```
router.get('/', function*(next) {
    this.body = 'test';
    var promise = Promise.resolve("test");
    var res = yield promise;
    this.body = res;
});
```